# Configure facebook login on localhost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, localhost

I want to add facebook login integration on my website and the problem is the facebook developer configuration to set to run on localhost environment (production is ok).

The error message:

> App Not Setup: This app is still in development mode, and you don't
>   have access to it. Switch to a registered test user or ask an app
>   admin for permissions

This question is not new but I did everything like the people told. Is there someone else having the same problem?

All the steps on facebook developer dashboard:

- is in `live` mode
- facebook login icon is `green`
- app domain: `localhost`
- privacy policy url: `yes`
- contact email: `yes`
- website url: `http://localhost:3000/`
- valid OAuth url: `http://localhost:3000/auth/facebook/callback`

I also tried `ngrok` to have a mask domain and I have the same problem even doing the same configuration as in the production mode (and working in production).

Answer (score 3):

I finally succeeded to get this to work. The problem with localhost it is that now facebook seems to requires on the api 3.2v to be https on the `OAuth url` field. So this field is automatically settled with 'https' prefix and eventually they'll not find what they want.

We have to use [ngrok](https://dashboard.ngrok.com/get-started) to mask our localhost and be able to use https.

The url is generated something like https://5za4e24b.ngrok.io

And the last thing is that on the OAuth field I filled up with two urls to `omniauth facebook` gem purpose:

- `https://5za4e24b.ngrok.io/auth/facebook`
- `https://5za4e24b.ngrok.io/auth/facebook/callback`

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can test facebook app with node.js callback your with ngrok. First problem https second ssl certificate.  Facebook will not authenticate .

Comment: Consider posting this as a comment instead of an answer. You will be able to post a comment after gaining certain number of reputation points.